# Haskell: How can I create an empty list as an option for a datatype?

Tags: list, haskell, types, declaration, ghci

In Haskell using the ghci compiler want to create a datatype which is either empty or has a triple. I tried to create an empty type but my data type E does not let me use it. How do you correctly declare this?

```
type Empty = []
data E = Zero Empty | Triple A B C
```

I keep getting this error: expecting one more argument to ‘Empty’
      Expected a type, but ‘Empty’ has kind ‘* -> *’

Comment: `[]` isn't a type; it's a type *constructor*.

Comment: By analogy with "Triple", "Quadruple", "Quintuple", should the constructor actually be named "Zerople"? =D

Comment: Sticking with Latin prefixes, it would be "Nilple", or to avoid autocorrect follies, "Nihilple".

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up type and data constructors, and using the *type* constructor `[]` (via the alias `Empty` where a plain type is expected.

Consider this pseudo-Haskell definition of the list constructor:

```
data [] a = [] | a : ([] a)
```

Here, `[]` is both the type constructor with kind `* -> *` and the nullary data constructor with type `[a]` representing empty lists.

For your type, do the same: `Zero` is just a nullary data constructor.

```
data E = Zero | Triple A B C
```

(assuming `A`, `B`, and `C` are fixed types. If you are trying to define triple of arbitrary types, you need to parameterize `E`:

```
data E a b c = Zero | Triple a b c
```

).